# Problem with Regular Expression on QA Environment server

Tags: java, encoding, urlencode

I want to encode a String to send it to a third-party service using a public key. It works fine on local PC (windows 7), but when deployed on server (Red Hat Linux Server) it's not working as expected and therefore the service is returning error

An example was given by the third-party company to consume the service and was used to implement the client as given:

```
PGPEncryptor encryptor = new PGPEncryptor();
String name = encryptor.encrypt(request.getName(), publicKey);

name = URLEncoder.encode(name , StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
                .replaceAll("\\%0D%0A", "\\\\r\\\\n")
                .replaceAll("%3A", ":")
                .replaceAll("\\+", " ")
                .replaceAll("\\%2F", "/")
                .replaceAll("\\%2B", "+")
                .trim();
```

When tested on local PC it gives

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----\r\nVersion: BCPG v1.23\r\n\r\nhQEMA....(A LOT OF CHAR)......pK9Q\r\n-----END PGP MESSAGE-----\r\n
```

But on server the output is

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----%0AVersion: BCPG v1.23%0A%0AhQEMA....(A LOT OF CHAR).........DVI6O%0A-----END PGP MESSAGE-----%0A
```

As if the result on `URLEncoder.encode` was not getting replaced by `replaceAll` function after.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

EDIT:

Value from **name** on Windows before `URLEncoder.encode`  is:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: BCPG v1.23

hQEMA9CJDjcM+dYnAQf/Tf1a3cdlBU441cW+Xf6RLPUQ+EebbPP2RvU6zx/wxhci
YJnJqCHzyUVnIVEeVgeMgqAYDgtQAHmywnzB6wL3BMkVl1Ok108/1/zjEbKKyLeX
tpX3ovW0Rcs25CwqOgybhyejHI2pZOz58T2LbhtZnMPn4jQrp1WuAbOqa4iSMIKc
48AQY8yeksbOHmnQAJi98wNc+dRoUQMlHX3GpWT1/fI2U5m20yMuPlZLyiax6ER6
dJ44EVypxPyjmEULgXnGw7vp76P43kwO5mzQbVHU2EXY9TsERieBqE/+/0AHrDtf
p2yY4kN2JSaEnHXm38Hh4UIszXG2WRm65bkJEzuxwMkhDOqGhbeJdGcjnGkMG45F
gbxTqsIzeRx9895LB0K8C90M
=Yu1E
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Comment: `String name` does not contain `\r` on Linux so your replace pattern fails. Please post an example of that string from windows.

Comment: As a side note (though not the reason for the problem), you can use `String.replace` instead of `replaceAll`, since the latter one uses regexes which appears to not be needed in your use case.